# altering table to add unique columns sql ce

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to add a column on my table using SQL Compact Edition. It used to work before but I am getting an error now that says

> A duplicate value cannot be inserted into a unique index. [ Table name = final try,Constraint name = UQ__final try__0000000000000228 ]

i'm using C# because i am getting the new column name (using textbox) and determine if the column is unique(checkbox). it used to work then suddenly it isn't. please help! my code is kinda messy. i'm sorry here it is:

```
string constr = "ALTER TABLE ";
if (textBox2.Text.ToString() != "")
{
    constr += "[" + table + "] ADD [" + col1 + "]";
    if (comboBox2.Text == "text")
    {
        constr += " nvarchar(300)";
    }
    else if (comboBox2.Text == "number")
    {
        constr += " int";
    }
    else if (comboBox2.Text == "date")
    {
        constr += " datetime";
    }
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        constr += " unique";
    }
}
cmd.CommandText = constr;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The `constr` outputs something like

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN column1 int unique
```

Please help! Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I discovered I cannot add a column only if the data grid view already have its data inside. What should I do? Help! Thanks!!!

Comment: The problem seems come from the DataGridView, not the alter table sql...

Comment: you can add columns to the table when the table is filled, but not when the field is NOT NULL or UNIQUE. When the field is not null you have to provide a default value and if you want it to be unique you have to add the column without unique and then create an unique index that allows nulls after the column creation

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with sql server ce but in normal sql server creating a column with the unique keyword means creating an index where no 2 rows can have a null in it because than they are not unique.

So you need to create your column without the unique keyword and than afterwards create an unique index that allows null.

You can create an unique index that ignores null values like this :

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_col1
ON dbo.MyTable(col1)
WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL;
```